# .htaccess Redirect index.php to other RewriteRule, results in loop, even with [L] flag

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

So I have this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^home$ /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^edit$ /edit.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /new.php
```

It will redirect any unknown url to `/new.php`

And only redirect the reserved `/home` and `/edit`, to the appropriate page

But I also want to redirect anyone going to the root `/` and `/index.php|html` to go to `/home`
So I tried with this:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.(php|html?)$ /home [R=301,L]
```

But it results in a loop, which is understandable.

It also breaks my `/home` redirect, by causing a loopback onto itself.
How do I get the `/` and `/index.php` to redirect to `/index.php`, but still adding the `/home` after it?

I also tried removing each of the RewriteCond lines, but it doesn't have any benefit..

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can rename index.php to home.php, that would seem to be the simplest way to avoid the circularity.

Comment: I like your thinking, but it still has the problem that when people fill in /home.php, it shows up in the URL, and I want to hide every possible .php or other file reference...

Comment: @TrySpace Just change it to `home-page-filename-people-will-never-guess.php`. Also note you have the same problem with edit.php and new.php.

Comment: Yeah, but still I'm wondering if it is possible in this scenario to ignore pretty much any file request, and redirect/rewrite them to /home or /new or /edit. It can't be impossible?